# How to automatically generate a test class name after selecting a fully-qualified class name to test?

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, phpstorm2017.3

I'm trying to create a new PHPUnit test class in PHPStorm. In the past when I've done this, when I fill in the *Fully Qualified Name* field with the class to test, the *Test Class Name* field would automatically update with 
"class name" + Test.

But now, for some reason the IDE is not prepending the class name. Is there a setting I need to turn on? I'm following [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.3/create-new-php-test-dialog.html?utm_medium=help_link&utm_source=from_product&utm_campaign=PS&utm_content=2017.3) and it says right on there that the default behavior

Comment: If you invoke autocompletion while typing your class name, does PHPStorm suggest the class you're wanting to test? The only reason I can see that it wouldn't generate the test class' name automatically was if it didn't find the class somehow.

Comment: PHPStorm correctly triggers the suggestions. Normally when I would select one, that's when it would populate the test class name for me. That's what's no longer working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there was an issue in PHPStorm 2017.3.1 because once I updated to 2017.3.6, I no longer have the issue.